# Construct pandas DataFrame from items in 3 level nested dictionary with to list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
data ={
    'Allehelgens gate 4': {
        'Direkte el1': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                537,
                967
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el2': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                100,
                89
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el3': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                203,
                191
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el4': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el5': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                8993,
                10113
            ]
        },
        'Fjernvarme6': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                10280,
                13630
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el7': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                1345,
                1380
            ]
        },
        'Tappevann8': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                9,
                15
            ]
        },
        'Tappevann9': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                8,
                15
            ]
        }
    },
    'Christian Krohgs gate 32': {
        'Fjernvarme1': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                9147,
                12761
            ]
        },
        'Fjernvarme2': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                8869,
                12732
            ]
        },
        'Fjernvarme3': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                50,
                1724
            ]
        },
        'Nærkjøling4': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Nærkjøling5': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Fjernvarme6': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Nærkjøling7': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Fjernvarme8': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Nærkjøling9': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Fjernvarme10': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                2,
                1
            ]
        },
        'Nærkjøling11': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Fjernvarme12': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                1
            ]
        },
        'Nærkjøling13': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el14': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                8626,
                16143
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el15': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                18211,
                18211
            ]
        },
        'Fjernvarme16': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                20600,
                35310
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el17': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                95,
                138
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el18': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                358,
                357
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el19': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                130,
                130
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el20': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                331,
                472
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el21': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                309,
                355
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el22': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                382,
                698
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el23': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                373,
                440
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el24': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                173,
                183
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el25': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                706,
                1015
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el26': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                80,
                141
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el27': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                175,
                210
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el28': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                406,
                702
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el29': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                251,
                364
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el30': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                517,
                510
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el31': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                146,
                299
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el32': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                659,
                857
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el33': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                55,
                90
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el34': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                192,
                224
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el35': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                976,
                1009
            ]
        },
        'Tappevann36': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Tappevann37': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el38': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                654,
                2436
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el39': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                27,
                212
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el40': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                75,
                
393
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el41': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                82,
                323
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el42': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                8,
                584
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el43': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                9,
                842
            ]
        },
        'Direkte el44': {
            'Datetime': [
                '2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z',
                '2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'
            ],
            'Value': [
                695,
                905
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to transform the dictionary to a pandas data frame. I think the best way would like to get something like :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJloe.png)

Tried several ways without success, somebody do have a clue to how to solve this ?

It seems that the reply from  Tranbi almost works:

sugested solution:

```
series = pd.DataFrame(data).unstack()
cols = series.index
s = series.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["Datetime"], x["Value"])))
pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=cols).T
```

but when running

```
series = pd.DataFrame(data).unstack()"
```

the Pandas.Series gets a lot of NaN. This cause an erro when running

```
s = series.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["Datetime"], x["Value"])))
```

Do you have any clue about how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the nested dictionaries is a little intricate. You can first get the multi-index columns with unstack then transform the cell values to create a new dataframe:

```
series = pd.DataFrame(data).unstack().dropna()
s = series.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["Datetime"], x["Value"])))
pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=series.index).T
```

Edit: adding `dropna` following your edit

Output:

```
                   Building 1                           Building 2                  
           Energy consumption Water consumption Energy consumption Water consumption
2020-12-28                537               537                600               800
2021-01-04                967               967                700               500
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code does work on this more concise dictionary. In reality I have a dictionary that has the same structure but it as 26 buildings , and several more 2 level keys, although the values are always values of the key Datetime and Value for each 2 level key. when I try  "s = series.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["Datetime"], x["Value"])))" it does come an error "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable". Do you know what might be the problem! thanks a lot I feel that I am close to solve this issue

Comment: That's probably because you named your input dictionary `dict`. It conflicts with the dictionary constructor. Rename it to data or anything else

Comment: right. after doing that. It appears another error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" when running s = series.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["Datetime"], x["Value"]))). I noticed that the series object doesn't look as it should. The first key of the first level is alright. But the second key of the first level also has the keys of the second level, but the key of the third level and their values are missing. I am pretty sure the structure of the dictionary is the same as shown here...

Comment: Why don't you add a minimal sample causing this error to the question?

Comment: I did it thanks again for your help. I can send the dict file if there is some way. thanks again!

Comment: Please be sure to include a dictionary that others can import and work with (also that the incriminated cells are included). Please read [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: now you can reproduce the dict. thanks for your support

Comment: ok that's because the sublevels don't all have the same keys. Drop the empty elements with `dropna`: `series = pd.DataFrame(data).unstack().dropna()`

Answer (score 0):

just use a list to store the buildings number and use the index to reference the building. You can also change the name of the index column to be `Building`. in other words you do not need `Building 1`, `Building 2`, ... , `Building n`

```
import pandas as pd

data = [

    {
        "Energy consumption": {
            "Datetime": ["2020-12-28","2021-01-04"],
            "Value": [537,967]},
        "Water consumption": {
            "Datetime": ["2020-12-28","2021-01-04"],
            "Value": [537,967]}
    },

    {
        "Energy consumption": {
            "Datetime": ["2020-12-28","2021-01-04"],
            "Value": [600,700]},
        "Water consumption": {
            "Datetime": ["2020-12-28","2021-01-04"],
            "Value": [800,500]}
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(df)
```

output:

```
                                  Energy consumption                                  Water consumption
0  {'Datetime': ['2020-12-28', '2021-01-04'], 'Va...  {'Datetime': ['2020-12-28', '2021-01-04'], 'Va...
1  {'Datetime': ['2020-12-28', '2021-01-04'], 'Va...  {'Datetime': ['2020-12-28', '2021-01-04'], 'Va...
```

Comment: Unfortunately the your output does not give a multi index column with dates as row index and values. I hope somebody else does know how to do it! thanks